How to chain strategies in a trading system
I have a list of strategies that are evaluated in a chain one after the other, in order based on some priority metric. If a strategy is activated and results in an order, the chain is broken and no other strategies are evaluated in this given time step. I'm re-evaluating this decision and wondering what is the best way to handle multiple strategies in a list of activated stocks in a given day.
On the flip side, when a strategy is activated previously, I have the choice to evaluate other strategies in case it gives me an opposite signal of the active trade, I can decide to close this position. But this can become complex quickly. So I also wonder if I should be mixing signals from different strategies or making them mutually exclusive and only act on the strategy that activated the trade.
Not much information around this online or other resources, since this is I think a design decision, I'm still wondering what is the recommendation from other algo-traders.
